# Мульти окно selenium

Tags: python, веб-программирование, selenium

У меня есть бот который авторизуется на сайте и выполняет на нем определенные действия, теперь мне нужно сделать так чтобы бот это делал с 50 аккаунтов одновременно, (Как это реализовать я понимаю), но вот как открыть 50 процессов при помощи selenium - нет

Answer (score 0):

Открыть одновременно можно через pytest
Но обратите внимание на ресурсы Вашего компьютера, Ваш компьютер сможет открыть 50 браузерных вкладок одновременно без экрана смерти?) Если нет, попробуйте потом в режиме `--headless`

Если ближе к делу, то Вам понадобится не просто pytest
Вам нужно установить pytest

```
pip install pytest
```

После, Вам понадобится установить xdist для `pytest`, который умеет работать с параллельным запуском

```
pip install pytest-xdist
```

Теперь когда у Вас всё установлено, необходимо будет прописать фикстуру параметризации над функцией, для большей информации советую ознакомиться [тут](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html)

После того как Вы ознакомились с построением и написанием `pytest`, Вам нужно будет воспользоваться терминалом в Вашем IDE, либо обычным. Команда следующая:

```
pytest -n 3 (Где 3 это количество одновременных запусков)
```

Также Вам нужно будет обратить внимание в какой директории Вы находитесь на данный момент. В IDE удобно: ПКМ по файлу Вашего проекта --> Open In --> Terminal. Тем самым Вы окажетесь в Вашем проекте, и пропишите команду которая прогонит все функции в этом файле. Если надо только одну то после `pytest -n 3` укажите путь до конкретной функции, к примеру:

```
pytest -n 3 .\tests\test_my_func.py
```

Если же Ваша функция в классе, тогда указываем сначала класс, потом метод(функцию) внутри этого класса, например:

```
pytest -n 3 .\tests\TestMyClass::test_my_func.py
```

Обращение к методам класса осуществляется двойным двоеточием.

Также обратите внимание, при использовании `pytest`, функцию которую Вы хотите запустить должна называться с `test_`, в противном случае он ее просто не увидит.
Аналогично с классами. TestMyClass

И в принципе всё. Запускайте Вашу функцию на здоровье.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!